# If Statement for nested attribute not working correctly on create action(Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have two models the first is called project and the second is status. Project accepts nested attr for my status model. That being said when I do an if statement in my project create action it seems like it isn't working. I dont get any errors and it doesnt send out my action mailer method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :status

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :status, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Here is my status model

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

## My status model actually has a column called status which is what I am trying to check on the create action in my project controller bellow.

Here is my project controller

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @project = Project.new(p_params)
    respond_to do |format|

      if @project.save
        #these if statements are the ones that aren't working.
        if @project.status == 'Production'
          ProjectMailer.alert_production(@project).deliver
        elsif @project.status == 'Design For Manufacturing'
          ProjectMailer.alert_dfm(@project).deliver
        elsif @project.status == 'Prototype'
          ProjectMailer.alert_prototype(@project).deliver
        elsif @project.status == 'Tooling'
          ProjectMailer.alert_tooling(@project).deliver
        elsif @project.status == 'Quality'
          ProjectMailer.alert_quality(@project).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to project_index_path, :notice => 'Project successfully created.' }
        format.xml { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def p_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:project_id, :in_visual, :planner, :part_num, :status, :customer, status_attributes: [:id, :a_d, :status, :note,
   :process,
   :sim_date, 
   :sim_reqs, :sim_def_quote, :tool_date, :tool_mat, :tool_o_source, :tool_insp, :tool_cust_paper, :tool_pro_ready, :pro_process, :pro_date])
  end
end
```

Comment: What did you try? Is there any validations on the project? are there any errors on the project instance?

Comment: This is what I am trying         #these if statements are the ones that aren't working.
        if @project.status == 'Production'

Comment: I am just trying to check if the my status is == "Production" @Albin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project has many Status object attached to it, then you need to decide which one is the one you care about. Is it the first one, is it the oldest one, is it the newest one, etc. The way that your code is written, you are comparing a Status object to a string. Try something like this:

```
      if @project.save
        # which status do you care about?
        status_that_matters = @project.statuses.first.status

        if status_that_matters == 'Production'
          ProjectMailer.alert_production(@project).deliver
        elsif status_that_matters == 'Design For Manufacturing'
          ProjectMailer.alert_dfm(@project).deliver
        elsif status_that_matters == 'Prototype'
          ProjectMailer.alert_prototype(@project).deliver
        elsif status_that_matters == 'Tooling'
          ProjectMailer.alert_tooling(@project).deliver
        elsif status_that_matters == 'Quality'
          ProjectMailer.alert_quality(@project).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to project_index_path, :notice => 'Project successfully created.' }
        format.xml { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
      end
```

Comment: Also You can change it to `case` statement. It'll be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Two other ways to do it:

```
 if @project.save
    # which status do you care about?
    status_that_matters = @project.statuses.first.status

    status_actions = { 
      'Production' => :alert_production,
      'Design For Manufacturing' => :alert_dfm,
      'Prototype' => :alert_prototype,
      'Tooling' => :alert_tooling,
      'Quality' => :alert_quality
    }

    action_method = status_actions[status_that_matters]
    ProjectMailer.send action_method, @project

    format.html { redirect_to project_index_path, :notice => 'Project successfully created.' }
    format.xml { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
  end
```

Makes it a bit cleaner in my opinion but adds the obscurity of a dynamic method call. It would also be easy to put the `status_actions` Hash in a configuration file.

Another fun option nowadays in Ruby is to switch on the String:

```
  if @project.save
    # which status do you care about?
    status_that_matters = @project.statuses.first.status

    case status_that_matters
    when 'Production'
      ProjectMailer.alert_production(@project).deliver
    when 'Design For Manufacturing'
      ProjectMailer.alert_dfm(@project).deliver
    when 'Prototype'
      ProjectMailer.alert_prototype(@project).deliver
    when 'Tooling'
      ProjectMailer.alert_tooling(@project).deliver
    when 'Quality'
      ProjectMailer.alert_quality(@project).deliver
    end

    format.html { redirect_to project_index_path, :notice => 'Project successfully created.' }
    format.xml { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
  end
```

I think I would prefer the last one!

Comment: I like the second option more thank you for all of your help! @froderik